# t.belongs_to and the effect on postgresql DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

```
class CreateCustomers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customers do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.string :firstname
      t.string :surname
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

These are my models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
end
```

Found the  `t.belongs_to :user` to add a foreign key in the database.
But when I check up my postgre database with pgadminIII, there is no foreign_key listed.
The migration adds the user_id as it should, but no foreign_key listed.

Any explanation for that?

best regards
denym

Edit: More information on the `t.belongs_to`

```
create_table :accounts do |t|
  t.belongs_to :supplier
  t.string :account_number
  t.timestamps
end
```

This is one example of it. From the railsguide ebook chapter 2.

Comment: I usually use t.references :user, index: true for such scenarios and I know it works with PG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the first time I see this `belongs_to` thing, but to ad an index on a column in migration you need to write

```
t.belongs_to :user, index: true
```

(mind new hash syntax)

Comment: Thanks for that, it worked. this `t.belongs_to` was from the railsguide ebook. Edited my post for more information. on the t.belongs_to thing